# Finding a circuit in a weighted graph with weight closest to desired value

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

In an edge-weighted graph, is there an algorithm to find a circuit starting from a certain vertex, where the sum of the weights on the circuit is closest to a desired value?

For instance, say I want to find a jogging route starting and ending at my house that is as close to 5km as possible. In this example, the graph is a street map with weight meaning distance, and the circuit is my jogging route. I do not want to turn around half way down a street - only at intersections.

I can think of a solution to this where you want to find an exact solution:

1. Find all walks starting from desired vertex, with length $=$ desired length.
2. If solutions exist, they are the walks which are also circuits.

Is there an algorithm for finding an optimum circuit, even if a circuit of an exact length does not exist?

Comment: What about just looking at all possible routes and then comparing to find the best? It is a very restricted problem since you only need to look within a 5km radius.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying - I can cull any vertex more than 5km from the starting point. This is a good point

Comment: Well, 10km, since anything longer than 10km will be worse than the trivial circuit

Comment: In general, this is NP-Complete, so there's no known algorithm for that.  To see it, set all weights to one and set the desired value to $n$, the number of vertices.  Finding the closest circuit means finding the longest cycle, which is NP-Complete.  Maybe if your streets are shaped like a grid though, it might help.